# Install Ubuntu while running Windows 8

Tags: installation, dual-boot, uefi

I am trying to install ubuntu onto my secondary HDD (F). I have windows 8 installed on my primary ssd (C). I have an iso file of the 64 bit ubuntu installation on a usb. My question is can I install this directly onto the F drive or do I need to have the USB boot from restart. Also, my C drive is booting UEFI not SATA, I think this is the problem I had when trying the first time. Eventually I am trying to have my initial load screen ask me which OS I would like to boot into.
When I run the iso while in windows it takes me to the ubuntu installer screen where I specify language, password etc.
This is not through wubi, I have tried that and got nothing but problems. I wanted a proper opinion before I make another drive useless and have to format.

Comment: Note that UEFI and SATA are not mutually exclusive technologies. The Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) is a type of firmware that's replacing the ancient BIOS. Serial Advanced Technology Attachment (SATA) is a type of hardware interface for hard disks. Most modern computers use both UEFI and SATA.

Answer (score 2):

### Install Ubuntu while running Windows 8

No you can't install Ubuntu while running Windows, you will have to boot from the USB.

### Install Ubuntu on UEFI enabled hardware

In most cases it is just necessary to boot Ubuntu and install it that Ubuntu will handle the UEFI settings for you. Learn more about UEFI [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).

**Troubleshooting**

*Before following the instructions given here, see [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System).*

Although if after installation you don't be able to choose which OS to use and your system simply start Windows 8, you will need to boot from the USB again, enable network connection and use the [Ubuntu Boot-Repair Tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

If your problem continues it means that your USB is not being booted in UEFI mode, so you will need to configure the BIOS to use only UEFI/EFI/Non-CSM Mode and if your system support the following features you will need to disable them: Secure Boot and Intel Rapid Response Technology/Intel VT-d/Intel Short Time Response. Some BIOS has an easy option: boot USB in UEFI mode, if you have this option enable it.

Then just install Ubuntu again, it is better not to choose the option Reinstall Ubuntu, but instead choose the Advanced Options, select the Ubuntu partition and mark it to be formatted and use "ext4 with journaling", then install it.

Then if you still don't get to the "choose OS screen" at boot time, run Boot-Repair once more time and everything would get fine.